# RadSideDrawer integration in angular not working properly

Tags: angular, webpack, nativescript

I am learning about angular integration with nativescript. For that I am developing a mobile app along with a web appp. I integrated **RadSideDrawer** into my app as shown in [this](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/Controls/Angular/SideDrawer/getting-started) guide. The mobile app works properly but when I serve the application to run on web i.e angular app, It throws following error.

> WARNING in ./node_modules/tns-core-modules/profiling/profiling.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '~/package.json' in
>   '/home/user/test/node_modules/tns-core-modules/profiling'
>
> ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/builder/component-builder/component-builder.js
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../../platform' in
>   '/home/user/test/node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/builder/component-builder'
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/core/bindable/bindable.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../../utils/utils' in
>   '/home/user/test/node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/core/bindable'
>
> ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/tns-core-modules/file-system/file-name-resolver/file-name-resolver.js
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../platform' in
>   '/home/user/test/node_modules/tns-core-modules/file-system/file-name-resolver'
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/builder/builder.js Module
>   not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../platform' in
>   '/home/user/test/node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/builder'
>
> ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/content-view/content-view.js Module
>   not found: Error: Can't resolve '../core/view' in
>   '/home/user/test/node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/content-view'
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/placeholder/placeholder.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../core/view' in
>   '/home/user/test/node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/placeholder'
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/repeater/repeater.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../label' in
>   '/home/user/test/node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/repeater'
>
> ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/proxy-view-container/proxy-view-container.js
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../layouts/layout-base' in
>   '/home/user/test/node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/proxy-view-container'[39[39mm
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/repeater/repeater.js
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../layouts/layout-base' in
>   '/home/user/test/node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/repeater'
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/repeater/repeater.js
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../layouts/stack-layout' in
>   '/home/user/test/node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/repeater'
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/tns-core-modules/utils/debug.js Module not
>   found: Error: Can't resolve '../platform' in
>   '/home/user/test/node_modules/tns-core-modules/utils'
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/tns-core-modules/text/formatted-string.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../ui/core/view' in
>   '/home/user/test/node_modules/tns-core-modules/text'
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/tns-core-modules/text/span.js Module not
>   found: Error: Can't resolve '../ui/core/view' in
>   '/home/user/test/node_modules/tns-core-modules/text'
>
> ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/nativescript-ui-sidedrawer/angular/side-drawer-directives.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './..' in
>   '/home/user/test/node_modules/nativescript-ui-sidedrawer/angular'
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/tns-core-modules/file-system/file-system.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './file-system-access' in
>   '/home/user/test/node_modules/tns-core-modules/file-system'

The code for my app is as below: 
`app.module.ts :`

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AutoGeneratedComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    HomeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

`app.module.tns.ts :`

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AutoGeneratedComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    HomeComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    NativeScriptModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    NativeScriptFormsModule,
    NativeScriptHttpClientModule,
    NativeScriptUISideDrawerModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

`home.component.ts :`

```
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  private _mainContentText: string;

  constructor(private _changeDetectionRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {
  }

  @ViewChild(RadSideDrawerComponent) public drawerComponent: RadSideDrawerComponent;

  private drawer: RadSideDrawer;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.mainContentText = "SideDrawer for NativeScript can be easily setup in the HTML definition of your page by defining tkDrawerContent and tkMainContent. The component has a default transition and position and also exposes notifications related to changes in its state. Swipe from left to open side drawer.";
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.drawer = this.drawerComponent.sideDrawer;
    this._changeDetectionRef.detectChanges();
  }

  get mainContentText() {
    return this._mainContentText;
  }

  set mainContentText(value: string) {
    this._mainContentText = value;
  }

  public openDrawer() {
    this.drawer.showDrawer();
  }

  public onCloseDrawerTap() {
    this.drawer.closeDrawer();
  }

}
```

`home.component.tns.html :`

```
<RadSideDrawer #sidedrawerId tkExampleTitle tkToggleNavButton>
  <StackLayout tkDrawerContent class="sideStackLayout">
    <StackLayout class="sideTitleStackLayout">
      <Label text="Navigation Menu"></Label>
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout class="sideStackLayout">
      <Label text="Primary" class="sideLabel sideLightGrayLabel"></Label>
      <Label text="Social" class="sideLabel"></Label>
      <Label text="Promotions" class="sideLabel"></Label>
      <Label text="Labels" class="sideLabel sideLightGrayLabel"></Label>
      <Label text="Important" class="sideLabel"></Label>
      <Label text="Starred" class="sideLabel"></Label>
      <Label text="Sent Mail" class="sideLabel"></Label>
      <Label text="Drafts" class="sideLabel"></Label>
    </StackLayout>
    <Label text="Close Drawer" color="lightgray" padding="10" style="horizontal-align: center" (tap)="onCloseDrawerTap()"></Label>
  </StackLayout>
  <StackLayout tkMainContent>
    <Label [text]="mainContentText" textWrap="true" class="drawerContentText"></Label>
    <Button text="OPEN DRAWER" (tap)="openDrawer()" class="drawerContentButton"></Button>
  </StackLayout>
</RadSideDrawer>
```

`home.component.html :`

```
<p>
  home works!
</p>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance :)

Comment: tns-core-modules / any nativescript specific plugins or code should never be part of your web app.. What you have in your web component?

Comment: @Manoj I thought so too but now I am too confused. Could you please help me out. I am a total noob and hoping to get some answers here. I have edited my question and added the code too. please have a look.

Comment: Try removing anything related to nativescript from your `home.component.ts`, the RadSideDrawer related stuffs. Let me know if that fixes the issue.

Comment: thank you your answer helped me a lot. I found the solution. Its actually we need to create separate components for web and mobile if we are going to use plugins from nativescript. Anyways thanx a lot @manoj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution to this question. Its just that we need to rename `home.component.ts` to `home.coponent.tns.ts` and then create another `home.component.ts` for the web view. With this we don't need to use any nativesctipt plugin into the web app and there will not be any of those errors.For those who want to research further more, More research materials can be found [here](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/code-sharing/platform-specific-components).

Comment: I have followed this https://docs.nativescript.org/code-sharing/code-splitting
and created service for drawer but when i compile for web it break say

ERROR in ./node_modules/tns-core-modules/application/application.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@nativescript/core/application/application' in 'D:\Vineet\Projects\Extra\Notes\ui\angular8\node_modules\tns-core-modules\application'
i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.